# aplicar efecto al cambiar de imagen con javascript

Tags: javascript, css, slider

necesito poder agregar un efecto cuando cada ciertos segundo cambia la imagen, para que el cambio no sea tan notorio, algún capo que me orientar!

lo que hace esta función es cambiar de imagen cada 5 segundos y es en el cambio que necesito pode aplicar algún tipo de efecto

```
    var contador=0;
function rotarImagenes(){
    var com = data.length-1;
    if(contador > com){
        contador = 0;
    }
    $('.home_banner_area .box_1620').css({
        "background": 'url("'+data[contador].img_slider+',"',
        'background-size': 'cover',
        'min-height': '650px',
        'border-radius': '12px',
        'position': 'relative',
        'bottom': '-120px'
     })

    contador++;
    }

 onload=function(){
    rotarImagenes();
    setInterval(rotarImagenes,5000);
}
```

Comment: puedes agregarlo a la propiedad  [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transition) a tu css

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrías agregar a tu css este código(sirve para el efecto).

```
    .flip-scale-2-ver-right {
    -webkit-animation: flip-scale-2-ver-right 0.5s linear both;
            animation: flip-scale-2-ver-right 0.5s linear both;
     }

@-webkit-keyframes flip-scale-2-ver-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0) scale(1);
            transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
            transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotateY(-90deg) scale(2);
            transform: translateX(50%) rotateY(-90deg) scale(2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-180deg) scale(1);
            transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-180deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
            transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
}
@keyframes flip-scale-2-ver-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0) scale(1);
            transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
            transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotateY(-90deg) scale(2);
            transform: translateX(50%) rotateY(-90deg) scale(2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-180deg) scale(1);
            transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(-180deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
            transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  }
}
```

Y luego en tu JS deberia aplicarle la clase css de esta manera. O intenta en otro lugar de tu js, pero la idea es agregarle la clase .flip-scale-2-ver-right. Como sigue

```
$('.home_banner_area .box_1620').addClass('flip-scale-2-ver-right');
$('.home_banner_area .box_1620').css({
    "background": 'url("'+data[contador].img_slider+',"',
    'background-size': 'cover',
    'min-height': '650px',
    'border-radius': '12px',
    'position': 'relative',
    'bottom': '-120px'
 })
```